# Unable to configure flutter web with https connection

Tags: flutter

I have did multiple process to configure my flutter web from `http://localhost` to `https://localhost`.

Like I have created certificate as below process
`openssl genrsa -out localhost.key 2048` to create private key file

Generate certificate signing request (CSR):

```
openssl req -new -key localhost.key -out localhost.csr -subj "/CN=localhost"
```

Generate self-signed certificate using CSR and key:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in localhost.csr -signkey localhost.key -out localhost.crt
```

I have added these .key and .csr file with creating a folder called cert and added the above created certificate.

then I have try with `flutter run --web-launch-url=https://localhost:8444` no luck getting error as `https://localhost:8444` is not a valid HTTP URL.

I have created "serve.json" file as set-up like

```yaml
{
   "request_handlers": [
    {
      "url_pattern": "/",
      "delegate": {
      "require_trusted_origin": false,
      "delegate_name": "flutter-tools/web-server",
      "secure": true,
      "web-port": 8444,
      "key_path":"cert/localhost.key",
      "certificate_path":"cert/localhost.crt"
     }
   }
]
    }
```

and run the command - as flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8444, it is still open the http://locallost:8444

Then I have tried wile creating "webdev.yaml" file with configuration

```yaml
serve:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8444
    use_https: true
    certificate_path: cert/localhost.crt
    key_path: cert/localhost.key
    https_port: 8444
```

and active the webdev with command flutter pub global activate webdev
and run the command to open the chrome with https "webdev serve"
still it id going on "http" not on "https"

And no luck till day end. I need to open my localhost with https as secure service.

Comment: Why do you care, when debugging, whether the debug framework uses http or https?

Comment: Because I have made some socket.io call which must be run on secure service, also when I am using webRTC , I must be run on https.

Comment: Any support from any where please. I am still struggling for same. Does it not work for debugging/development.